# How to select dropdown item with same data-testid

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to get selenium to click an option in a dropdown. There are several options and it looks like the only unique thing about them is the link text. They all have 'data-testid' and they are all the same.
Anyone see a way to click a specific choice within the dropdown?

Here are a few examples of options within the dropdown: (App installs and Lead Generation)

```
<li class="" data-testid="ads-mini-grouped-objective-selector-option" style=""><div aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" class="_2wpb _3v8w" data-testid="SUISelectorOption/container" role="menuitem" style="letter-spacing: normal; color: rgb(75, 79, 86); font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 16px; padding: 6px 24px 6px 32px;" tabindex="-1"><span class="_27_z _4s-j" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 8px;"></span><div class="_3leq"><span>App installs</span></div></div></li>

<li class="" data-testid="ads-mini-grouped-objective-selector-option" style="background-color: rgba(29, 33, 41, 0.08);"><div aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" class="_2wpb _3v8w" data-testid="SUISelectorOption/container" role="menuitem" style="letter-spacing: normal; color: rgb(75, 79, 86); font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 16px; padding: 6px 24px 6px 32px;" tabindex="-1"><span class="_27_z _5da8" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 8px;"></span><div class="_3leq"><span>Lead generation</span></div></div></li>
```

I have tried to select by link text but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click an *option* from the *Dropdown* you can write a function as `clickOption()` as follows :

```
public void clickOption(String option)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@data-testid='ads-mini-grouped-objective-selector-option']//span[.='" + option + "']")).Click();
}
```

Now, from your `main(`) or `@Test` annotation Class, call the function `clickOption()` method with the option which you want to select as follows :

```
clickOption("App installs");
//or
clickOption("Lead generation");
```

Comment: Your function is exactly what I was looking for. This helps a lot and worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//li[@data-testid='ads-mini-grouped-objective-selector-option'])[2]")).click();
```

Try this xpath to click second data with same data-testid:

Comment: I would rather a more accurate way. What happens if the dropdown options order change? Is there a way I could incorporate that with the link text? @deepan

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to select `li` element by attribute `data-testid` and inner text :

```
//li[@data-testid='ads-mini-grouped-objective-selector-option' and .='Lead generation']
```

Answer (score 0):

har07 answer is a good answer,
you can also try this as an option

```
//*[text()='App installs']/parent::div/parent::div/parent::li
```

Because not all the html is given, this is the only option i can get